# Does our heart stop when we sneeze?

Tags: human-biology, cardiology

Is it [fact](http://www.uamshealth.com/heartmyth) or [myth](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/11-surprising-sneezing-facts?page=2) that our heart stops beating for moments when we sneeze? If it is fact, what drives the heart to start beating again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your linked [fact from the University of Arkansas](http://www.uamshealth.com/heartmyth)

> When you sneeze, the intrathoracic pressure in your body momentarily increases. This will decrease the blood flow back to the heart. The *heart compensates* for this by changing its regular heart beat momentarily to adjust. However, the **electrical activity of the heart does not stop** during the sneeze.

...as well as your ['myth' from webMD](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/11-surprising-sneezing-facts?page=2)

> For instance, it's ***not true that your heart stops*** when you sneeze. When your chest contracts because of a sneeze, your blood flow is momentarily constricted as well. As a result, the rhythm of your heart may change, but it definitely doesn't stop.

...come to the **same conclusion**, namely the heart does not stop during a sneeze.

Comment: Isn't the length of a sneeze less than the time between resting heartbeats, at least for most healthy people?  So it seems odd to say that the heart would stop.